# I can run only commands which produces output less than 25 line in centos

Tags: centos, ssh

I am connecting to a centos server with ssh and try to execute some commands. But if this commands output is bigger than 25 line, it fails and I can't do anything else in this ssh session. Is there any limit for terminal output?

For example

ifconfig>>output.txt -> There is no error in this command

ifconfig-> This command fails and ssh session drop after some time. I can establish another ssh session and run executable commands during ssh drop time.

If there is a limit for terminal output, how can I change this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe how `ifconfig` fails? Does anything happen between the failure and the connection drop? Can you enter anything after the failure?

Comment: I expect to see output of ifconfig but I can't see this. ifconfig fails means there is no output for this command. And this command drops my ssh session, I cannot enter any other command during or after connection drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a long shot since there is not much information to go by, but I have stumbled upon similar issues a couple of times.

It could be network MTU (maximum transmission unit) issues disrupting the network traffic. Small packets in the SSH session works fine, like single commands, or just a couple of lines transferred. But when lots of output is being transferred, the network packets grow over a certain size, and is dropped by a firewall or a router.

If you have a firewall between you and the server, this would be a good place to look for this issue. Logs may reveal why the session is dropped.

More info on MTU and how to debug such issues can be found here:

https://fasterdata.es.net/network-tuning/mtu-issues/debugging-mtu-problems/

Comment: Thank you very much. It fixed when I decrease server mtu size.